# Android: make dynamically added imageviews full screen on click

Tags: java, android

This is an often asked question but I just can't find the right solution for my case. I'm working on a news app and I want to fullscreen images in the news content when the user clicks the image, and another click will return to the news page. In my code, I have an ArrayList of data with the type of image or text, this method will go through the ArrayList and dynamically add an image view or text view according to the type. The code is like

```
    public void setText(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> datas) {
    for (HashMap<String, String> hashMap : datas) {
        String type = hashMap.get("type");
        if (type.equals("image")) {
            int imagewidth = mTypedArray.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.styleable.customTextView_image_width, 100);
            int imageheight = mTypedArray.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.styleable.customTextView_image_height, 100);
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            params = new LayoutParams(imagewidth, imageheight);
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;    
            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);

            addView(imageView);

            DownloadPicTask task = new DownloadPicTask(imageView, handler);
            task.execute(hashMap.get("value"));
        } else {
        //Add some text view
        }
```

I have tried simply changing the image to FIT_XY on click, but only the last spawned image enlarged, and I don't want other content to still remain around the image.

Perhaps I should set an onclick listener to each image, then create a new fullscreen activity? But I'm new to android and I don't know how to pass the image data correctly to fullscreen activity, and how to make another click back to the original content.